# Java Assert Double is NaN

Tags: java, junit, assert, nan

I am trying to assert that my double is NaN. 
Here is a code snippet:

```
private Double calculateIt(String input){...}

assertEquals(Double.NaN, calculateIt("input text"));
```

The code does not compile, `Double.NaN` is defined as primitive

```
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

To make the assertion work I wrap NaN with a Double object.

```
assertEquals(new Double(Double.NaN), calculateIt("input text"));
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Better is a matter of opinion

Answer (score 10):

You could use:

```
boolean isNan = Double.isNaN(calculateIt("input text"));
assertTrue(isNan);
```

`Double.NaN` values cannot be compared with `==` (`Double.NaN == Double.NaN` will return `false`), because `NaN` is considered as a special one.

More info:

- [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals(Double.NaN, calculateIt(...), 0.0)` with [assertEquals(double, double, double)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)

or

`assertThat(calculateIt(...), isNan())` with [Hamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/number/IsNaN.java).

> better way of doing this

What best shows the intent? Which can you skim read and easily see what the method is testing?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
assertTrue(Double.compare(Double.NaN, calculateIt("input text")));
```

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter is `Double.valueOf("NaN")` or with a static import `valueOf("NaN")`, but it's basically the same as you already have.